# What is equivalent GetPropValue<T> method in L2E?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, flexigrid

I´m have a problem using EF for my data model.

I have this code in my method:

```
  listaPaginada = sortOrder.Equals("asc") ?
                    _cadastroServ.SelecionaNotasFiscais(idParceiro).OrderBy(i =>   i.GetType().GetProperty(query)) :
                    _cadastroServ.SelecionaNotasFiscais(idParceiro).OrderByDescending(i => i.GetType().GetProperty(query));
```

i´m using the same method hear to:

```
Func<NotaFiscal, bool> whereClause = (i => i.GetPropValue<string>(sortName).Contains(query));
            listaPaginada = sortOrder.Equals("asc", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ?
                _cadastroServ.SelecionaNotasFiscais(idParceiro).Where(whereClause).OrderByDescending(i => i.GetPropValue<IComparable>(sortName)) :
                _cadastroServ.SelecionaNotasFiscais(idParceiro).Where(whereClause).OrderBy(i => i.GetPropValue<IComparable>(sortName));
```

In L2SQL the method  GetPropValue exists, but in L2E not.

Someone knows a similar method in L2E ? 
or knows how to solve this ?

Regards[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `GetPropValue` in LINQ-to-SQL. Are you sure it exists? That said, it's easy enough to conjure up what this method is doing and write accordingly:

```
static class ObjectExtensions {
    public static T GetPropValue<T>(this object value, string propertyName) {
        if (value == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("value"); }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName)) { throw new ArgumentException("propertyName"); }
        PropertyInfo info = value.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
        return (T)info.GetValue(value, null);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class Test {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}

Test test = new Test() { Name = "Jenny", Number = "8675309" };
Console.WriteLine(test.GetPropValue<string>("Name"));
Console.WriteLine(test.GetPropValue<int>("Number"));
```